# Dynamic RESTful urls OR add RESTful listener at runtime

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, dynamic, java-ee-6

I've got a Java EE application which uses restful urls (JAX-RS), something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/{id}")
public void foo(....
```

What I need to do is add some of these urls on runtime. Probably something in this direction:

```
@Inject
RestfulController rC; 

void myMethod(){
    rC.registerPath( GET, "/xxx/" + var1 + "/{asfd}", listener);
}
```

I found a very similar question without an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488031/develop-a-dynamic-rest-web-server-using-java-ee#comment41094132_12488031

Is there any way to register new URLs at runtime?

Edit: For my use case it would be enough that I could set the urls (and listeners) once at startup. There is no need to change them afterwards. The only point is that they can't be hard-coded for example with @Path.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation you use?

Comment: I currently use JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final that mean RESTEasy should be the implementation ... if you ask that question I quess there is no implementation-independent solution, isn't it?

Comment: No it would be rather talking about vendor specific features better that implementation dependent solution.